# Unable to change foreground color of label in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, foreground

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGnmP.png)

It's grayed out by default .so, I want it to be black by default. This is Foreground color property of Label in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: The label's "default color" is defined by the installed look and feel, it's unlikely you're going to be able to change this from within Netbeans Form Editor, you're going to have to change the default color supplied by the look and feel from within code. How you do this (and the keys you need) will depend on the target look and feel you want to use

Comment: when I drag it, I want it to be black by default.

Comment: What you want and what the system will allow you to do are two different things, live with it

Comment: but in my friend's computer, the default label's foreground value is black. So I thinks I can do somthing to change the default value of this. please help me.

Comment: Change the look and feel that Netbeans is using

Comment: I was able to solve it by changing the preferred look and feel to Windows mode instead of Flatlaf Dark mode. Thank you.

Comment: Just understand that, depending on the OS and how you setup you code, the L&F might be different from the one used by Netbeans